# Where to find DRF historical documentation?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I want to browse historical version of DRF documentation. Is there place where for example documentation for version 3.5.3 is available?

Answer (score 0):

The docs are hosted on [Github](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/master/docs) together with the code, so you can just use the branch/tag feature of Github to choose the version of the docs you want to read

Comment: yes but in this situation I must see raw md files without links, if this is only solution I will use this approach

Comment: @gelmir Github renders md files when you open them with all the markups intact. So it's actually almost the same as in the site